# Printing onto Vellum / Tracing Paper

Tags: print-design, paper, vellum, color-profile

I need to print form a Canon Pixma 100 Pro onto [vellum](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00BMO2TQQ/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

[image]

Whereas other paper I've printed onto has had printing profiles available for the paper (Canon, Hahnemuhle etc), this is generic unbranded paper.

I'm printing black text only, and I have done some tests with existing profiles. Though it's pretty successful, there is too much ink being put down.

Can anyone suggest a profile I can use for this paper?

Comment: I am not a digital print expert (I mostly do offset print). I guess you are printing RGB black, converted to be made of all 4 CMYK colors. Could you print just 100% black text? I mean you could also lighten the text color but it still need to look solid, right?

Comment: I am a bit puzzled by this question. At first i thought it was a bit overkill to need a color profile to lighten a black text, but maybe I am missing something about digital print? I thought the only thing thing a color profile could manage was the actual RGB/CMYK numbers. Your question make it sound like there are other ways the color profile can control the amount of ink? If the color profile only changes the numbers then you could do it manually. It is only one color to get right...

Comment: @MadsWolff Yes. I think you are correct. I am mixing things up. You are right that an ICC profile doesn't store information related to ink coverage. The ICC profile isn't an issue as the image is monochrome. I need to look at reducing ink coverage by amending the pdf I am printing. Thanks.